# React hooks, Why is it automatically re rendered when the DB value changes?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-state

First of all, I use Firebase to structure my DB.

I saved my db value through useState like this way.

```
const getFromFirestore = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("GET From Firestore");
    webtoonSites.forEach((siteName) => {
      days.forEach(async (day) => {
        await dbService
          .collection(userObj.uid)
          .doc(siteName)
          .collection(day)
          .onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
            const webtoonArr = snapShot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
            setMyWebtoons((prev) => {
              return {
                ...prev,
                [siteName]: {
                  ...prev[siteName],
                  [day]: webtoonArr,
                },
              };
            });
          });
      });
    });
    setDataInit(true);
  }, [myWebtoons, userObj]);
```

And then,
I changed the DB value through Firebase because there was something to be deleted.

```
if (ok) {
        console.log("delete");
      await dbService
        .collection(userObj.uid)
        .doc(siteName)
        .collection(targetWebtoonObj.day)
        .doc(targetWebtoonObj.title)
        .delete();
    }
```

I thought that React would not have recognized that the DB value was changed, but it recognized it and took an automatic re-rendering process.

So I checked the execution of the function 'getFromFirestore' with console.log() that function sets the state value from the db , but it was not even executed.

When and how did React hooks recognized the db-changed and changed the state value...?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Firestore documentation on [listening for changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) (emphasis mine):

> You can listen to a document with the `onSnapshot()` method. An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. **Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot.**

So each time the data changes, your `onSnapshot` callback gets called *again*. And since you process the data in there again, and call `setMyWebtoons` again, the updated data is automatically rerendered. Pretty cool, right? :)

Comment: OMG...  So Pretty good !! thank you for your feedbak :)